# Snort: How to use custom Multi-Pattern Search Engine

Tags: pattern-matching, snort

I'm trying to benchmark my Multi-Pattern Search Engine against other algorithms included with [snort3](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/).

I'm trying to figure out what files from the repository I need to modify, and where should I add my files.

[image]
I'm only interested in the third part of the pipeline (Aho-Corasick-like), not the fourth one (PCRE-like).

This [thesis](https://github.com/jameskellynet/snort-ids-multi-pattern-matching/blob/master/thesis.pdf) helped me a bit, especially Appendix A starting from page 145. Unfortunately, Snort's codebase layout has changed a bit in the last 15 years.

The engine implementations seem to reside in [src/search_engines](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/tree/master/src/search_engines). Some implementations, like the [NFA-AC](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/blob/master/src/search_engines/bnfa_search.cc) don't seem to inherit from an interface like a more recent one does ([Hyperscan](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/blob/master/src/search_engines/hyperscan.cc)).

Does my search engine need to support all of the functionalities found in the `PatternDescriptor` from [src/framework/mpse.h](https://github.com/snort3/snort3/blob/master/src/framework/mpse.h#L65)?

How do I let snort know which engine to choose? My guess is that I have to modify `config detection: search-method ac-split` from `snort.conf`, but I'm not sure with what, since it wouldn't be the actual name of the search engine file.

Is there a more concrete resource on how to achieve this? Thank you!